# node.js fs.existsSync returns incorrect value for paths containing environment variables

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use [`fs.existsSync`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) to check whether a file exists. When the full filesystem path is entered, it returns successfully. When the path contains an environment variable like `~/foo.bar` or `$HOME/foo.bar`, it fails to find the file.

I have tried all of the methods from the path module to massage the path first, but nothing seems to work. I should note that the filepath is entered by the user either via command line or a JSON file.

I am aware that the environment variables live in `process.env`, but I was wondering if there is some way to handle this aside from a find/replace for every possible variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment variables are expanded by the shell.  Node's `fs` methods make filesystem calls directly.

Read the variable you need out of [`process.env`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) and use [`path.join`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) to concatenate.

```
path.join(process.env.HOME, 'foo.bar');
```

(Keep in mind there is no `HOME` variable on Windows if you need to be cross-platform; I believe it's `USERPROFILE`.)

---

Since you're dealing with user input, you're going to have to parse the path components yourself.

First, normalize the input string and split it into an array.

```
var p = path.normalize(inputStr).split(path.sep);
```

If the first element is `~`, replace it with the home directory.

```
if (p[0] == '~') p[0] = process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE; // Windows
```

Then loop over each element, and if it starts with `$`, replace it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (p[i][0] == '$') {
        var evar = p[i].substr(1);
        if (process.env[evar]) p[i] = process.env[evar];
    }
}
```

And finally, join the path array back together, re-normalizing:

```
path.join.apply(path, p);
```

Comment: I was really hoping the answer would be a builtin but this should work

Answer (score 2):

Use process.env.HOME instead? Then use path.join to get the correct path.

```
fs.existsSync(path.join(process.env.HOME,"foo.bar"));
```